# How to use boost to specifically negotiate null tls (1.2) cipher

Tags: c++, boost, tls1.2

We're operating in a TLSv1.2 environment, negotiating successfully with the server and maintaining a protocol. However we are stuck at a particular point and need to supply unencrypted pcaps to support people so they can diagnose the issue. Specifically, support won't help us if we don't present the pcap in NULL-SHA256.

Since normally our code negotiates successfully to a non-null cipher, we just added code restricting the context's cipher list to only contain NULL-SHA256 while retaining the rest of the setup. This context is used in the CTOR of a boost::asio::ssl::stream"&lt"boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket"&gt".

The server rejects our Client Hello. How can I successfully negotiate to the NULL-SHA256 cipher operating in a TLS1v1.2 environment?

Thanks

Context setup follows:

```
{
    bool success = false;
    char cipherBuff[200];
    sprintf(cipherBuff, "%s", TLS1_TXT_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256);
    if (int sclRet = (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, cipherBuff)) <= 0)
    {
        printf("SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list failed: %d\n", sclRet);
    }
    else
    {    
        if (m_ssl_client_certificate_path.size())
        {
            SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, m_ssl_client_certificate_path.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

            if (privateKeyBufferPtr && privateKeyBufferLen)
            {
                if ((kbio = BIO_new_mem_buf((char*)privateKeyBufferPtr, -1)) != NULL)
                {
                    if ((rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(kbio, NULL, 0, NULL)) != NULL)
                    {
                        success = (SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey((SSL_CTX*)ctx, rsa) == 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The boost::asio::ssl::stream template is passed a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket, this was lost in the comment because brackets.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to make adjustments. Please also extract a [mcve] from your code (Is Boosst relevant at all?) and make sure that those nasty C-style casts don't mess up things.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It will take a day or so to extract a runnable example, and will do, but was hoping someone with more experience would see this and just know what the problem is. Boost is a thin wrapper on openssl, it's claimed, but as before perhaps someone out there knows whether Boost is playing a role in the problem.

Comment: One more suggestion: Check upstream bugreports! If someone already solved your problem, it would probably be recorded there.